# Why do I get the 'Use of unresolved identifier' error when writing this code in Swift?

Tags: swift, if-statement

I have the following code:

```
let FOO = true
if (FOO) {
    let BAR = "Off"
} else {
    let BAR = "On"
}
print(BAR)
```

My problem that is the line that says `print(BAR)` returns the error:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'BAR'

From what I can see, there is no reason that this code shouldn't compile is there? The constant `BAR` will always be created so can always be printed to the console.

Comment: Most statically-typed languages don't allow this (with the exception of Crystal and I believe Kotlin). Just assign `bar` to `""` before the body.

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos So I guess then I'd have to use a variable not a content then wouldn't I. I just find it weird that I can'd do that.

Comment: @possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31598472/use-of-unresolved-identifier-when-using-for-loop-in-swift/31598610#31598610

Comment: @KianCross Yes. This type of analysis seems easy but is actually quite tricky it some cases. There's a short description [here](http://crystal-lang.org/2013/09/23/type-inference-part-1.html) (scroll to the "Conditionals" section).

Comment: Just a note: please note that variables/constants/functions names should be (by convention) lowercase and following theCamelCase rule. So 'bar' instead of 'BAR'.

Comment: You are right about Java and C++. However in Swift the convention is camelCase. Every constant in the Apple official Swift documentation is written this way. Sorry for my  note, I know it is not directly related to your question.

Comment: @KianCross it's not a convention in Swift, mostly because the language encourages you to declare everything as const (i.e. `let`) as default, and use `var` only when absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The scope of `BAR` is limited to the `if/else` so you can't refer to it later in the code.

But you can do

```
let foo = true
let bar: String
if (foo) {
    bar = "Off"
} else {
    bar = "On"
}
print(bar)
```

The compiler is able to realize that `bar` is assigned only once and before use, so this will compile just fine.

Comment: This is the perfect solution for this scenario.

Comment: or even shorter, the ternary operator: `let bar = foo ? "off" : "on"`

Comment: @Ian, well yes, I assumed this was a contrived example :)

Answer (score 1):

This is because BAR is a local variable of only the if and else statement, so try this code instead.

```
let FOO = true
var BAR = ""
if (FOO) {
   BAR = "Off"
} else {
   BAR = "On"
}
print(BAR)
```

Comment: Sorry, when I copy pasted his code I left it a let instead of a var

Comment: Now it will compile. However it would be more logic to avoid the initial assignment of an empty string to 'BAR' and making it a constant ('let').